# Connect Django 1.11 to Mariadb Galera cluster

Tags: python, django, mariadb, galera

I am using `Django 1.11` with `MariaDB 10.1 Galera cluster`
I didn`t find in the documentation how to connect to a cluster.

I tried using `gcomm://NODE1,NODE2` url with no success... any idea?

Comment: You can connect to one node by using the IP address of that node.  Load balancing  is another issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a ticket that I opened to `Django` project, there is no support in `MariaDB Galera cluster` and they probably will not add support for that soon

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28270

Answer (score 0):

You shall put a load balancer such as haproxy in front of your cluster, as all nodes of gelara cluster are same, this is fully acceptable for example:

```
apt-get install haproxy
sudo vi /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
# Add the following lines to the end of file:
listen galera
    # Replace "IP" by server local IP
    bind IP:3306
    balance roundrobin
    mode tcp
    option tcpka
    option mysql-check user haproxy
    # Replace "IP" by galera-mariadb-1 local IP
    server galera-mariadb-1 IP:3306 check weight 1
    # Replace "IP" by galera-mariadb-2 local IP
    server galera-mariadb-2 IP:3306 check weight 1
    # Replace "IP" by galera-mariadb-3 local IP
    server galera-mariadb-3 IP:3306 check weight 1
# link: https://cyral.com/blog/how-to-galera-mariadb-haproxy/
```

Although this will result in a paradoxical situation where you find yourself not actually high available using one-node haproxy, that also is solvable using keepalived...